# htaccess 301 mod rewrite matching url pattern

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This one's beyond my ability I'm afraid and after much research and breaking things I've come for help. I have a site with a URL in the format of:

example.com/7865/travel-photo/my-amazing-photo

My client has now decided he'd like to add an 's' onto photos so the URL has become:

example.com/7865/travel-photos/my-amazing-photo

All great and that alone wouldn't have been a problem only for the fact that the number '7865' changes for each URL just like the 'my-amazing-photo' does. The basic structure of the new URL needs to be:

example.com/'number variable'/travel-photos/'article name variable'

So my question how does write a beautiful htaccess mod rewrite rule for that?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/travel-photos/(.*) $1/travel-photo/$2
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Gerben. I had tried that exact code except mine looked like this:  

`RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/travel-photos/(.*)$ $1/travel-photo/$2 [R=301]`  

I've had no luck with either option unfortunately. Not sure if it matters but this is a WordPress blog.

Comment: I think the rule you need is: `^([^/]+)/travel-photo/(.*)$ /$1/travel-photos/$2 [NC,L,R=301]`

Comment: Aha, so you wanted it the other way around.